# how to access elements inside windows showModalDialog

Tags: jquery, selenium, modal-dialog

I am working on old web app automation using Selenium.
On clicking a button the application launches a windows showModelDialog window.
Inside this there are many elements (Buttons, text boxes) which needs to be accessed. (These are visible only in IE and I am automating using IE driver). 
My questions :

> 1. How do I access this model dialog (something like switch window, or switch using window handle ?? )
> 2. How can I access elements inside the model dialog and continue automation.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Tried this, but invain :(

here is the code snippet :

```
 Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();           
    for (String handle : handles) {
        System.out.println("handle = "+handle);
        if (!mainHandle.equals(handle)) {
            System.out.println("handle child = " + handle);
            WebDriver d = driver.switchTo().window(handle);
            System.out.println("swith title =" + d.getTitle());
            d.close(); //d.quit(); //both not working
        }
    }
```

here is the output :

```
main handle = 87bc0402-895d-4f9a-84c4-8324e023c05c
main title= ATCOMRES - Unit Promotion Rates
handle = 87bc0402-895d-4f9a-84c4-8324e023c05c
handle = 347727e2-50d7-4ae9-a0f3-80eafeff844f
handle child = 347727e2-50d7-4ae9-a0f3-80eafeff844f
swith title =Inventory
```

Answer (score -1):

This question is answered a lot on SO . selenium provides the functions for switching between windows,frames and alerts using handles .
A search on these two functions would help you get going.
driver.getWindowHandles() and 
driver.switchTo().window()

Comment: thanks @user1155838, we have already tried these.

I have edited the question and included code and corresponding output.
We are struggling to proceed after this step.
For ex, We are not able to close the window  (d.close() in the code failed)
Also, this dialog contains rich elements, and how to access them (for ex, text box, buttons, check boxes etc)

Comment: Does driver.close() fail in all browsers or any one in specific ? The process to fetch the elements in the dialog is same as that of normal page . You would have to share the html sample code for me to comment further on it.